# Remote query in MySQL using python

Tags: python, mysql

How can I query a remote MySQL database, write a select query and insert into my local mysql database using python?

Comment: [This guide](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) should help

Comment: How can I insert/update the destination? I read MySQL INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax,any example about this?

Answer (score 3):

Some tips to keep in mind:

1. MySQL by default does not listen on a public IP address. This means, even if the server is running; you may not be able to access it remotely.
2. Even if the server has been reconfigured to listen on the public IP address, your user account needs to be granted permission to connect from remote clients.

Once you have those two taken care of, make sure you are able to connect to server. Use the `mysql` client:

```
mysql -H remote.box.com -U yourusername -P
```

Next, you need to install the MySQL drivers for Python.

- On Ubuntu/Kubuntu/Debian: `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`
- On RedHat/Fedora/CentOS: `sudo yum install MySQL-python`
- On Windows: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ (search for MySQLdb)
- On Mac: `sudo pip install mysql-python`

Finally - read [this tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/) which will get you started.

Comment: Hi,i cannot open the tutorial you've given.

Comment: tutorial link WFM, nice answer -> +1 ;)